# Can I say "He would be taller more"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, spoken-english

We know we can't say more taller but can we say

> He would be taller more.

Comment: He would be **even** taller now. [after a period of time]

Comment: Taller already means *more tall*, as do most (all?) comparatives.  Mark is tall.  Dave is taller.  This implies Dave is more tall than Mark.

Comment: This question doesn't allow us to write a helpful reply.  Please explain what you are trying to say.  What you wrote is ungrammatical and nonsensical.

Comment: The answer to the question, exactly as written, is "No, not if you want to be grammatical."

Comment: Mark is tall. Dave is taller. Maria is even taller than Dave. Hadassah is taller still. Nils is taller than even Hadassah.… but at some point you stop trying to narrate these relationships and illustrate them instead.